# Order by a columnname in descending order

Tags: mysql, sorting

I want to to sort a column named "bname" using the descending order or a column named "count"

I have this code with me which is not sorted:

```
SELECT bname FROM brandnames HAVING count(*) > 0 LIMIT 11
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` is applied last, after aggregates So just `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC`

Comment: Do you want to order by a column named `count`, or order by `count(*)`?

Comment: You'll also need `GROUP BY bname`.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson I want to order by a column named count

Answer (score 1):

Just add the clause ORDER BY like this:

```
ORDER BY bname DESC
```

The DESC will order your results in descendant order. You can remove DESC and your results will be ascendant.

See more here: ["Order by" optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT bname
FROM brandnames
HAVING count(*) > 0 
ORDER BY bname DESC
LIMIT 11
```

Comment: The wording is a little confusing, but I think the OP wants to sort by `count`, not `bname`.

Comment: I tried this before also but it only shows 1 row with the top count:(

Comment: @MiteshMynee That's because you need the `GROUP BY`. It's MySQL's strange aggregate behavior.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski when I add group by I get a "warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given" That's why I removed it.

Comment: @MiteshMynee That's an unrelated problem with your PHP code.  It means you forgot to pass the link resource param to `mysqli_error()`. But it may have been triggered because you got your syntax wrong.

Comment: $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
if (!$result)
{die('error' . mysqli_error());}

This is the php code

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski you are mistaken. Far from "essential", `GROUP BY` is not required in mysql.

Comment: @Bohemian No it is not required, but selecting `bname` without it makes the aggregate `COUNT()` unreliable and basically meaningless.  Only one row will ever be returned and its count value won't have a meaningful relationship with the indeterminate `bname` returned along with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY _column_ ASC/DESC`

```
SELECT bname FROM brandnames HAVING count(*) > 0 ORDER BY bname DESC LIMIT 11
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  ORDER BY bname DESC
```

append that to the end of your SQL statement.

`ORDER BY` orders by specific field.

`DESC` refers to descending. Which means reverse alphabetical or reverse numerical, or reverse date order.

Depending on the type. Remove the `DESC` and it'll automatically do ascending.

Good luck!